# What filter to apply on image when I would use overlay text on it?

Tags: images, overlay

I have following photo, I would use a text on the left side, but neigther white not black fits well. Is it any trick / filter I can apply to make look good?

[image]

Try to use this image: https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/dating-at-bar-gm471094306-63343095

I woudl buy the image without water marks later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two very simple options for text against variable background would be to add a contrasting stroke, or a drop shadow [spread evenly as a fade, not as a true 'drop'].
Use white with black text & black with white text - but don't mix the two.

Examples - rough as heck because the original is tiny…

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I, personally am never a fan of using strokes or shadows to boost contrast if they can be avoided. They *absolutely* work and many people like to use them - there's certainly *no harm* in using them if thats your preference. I try and find *other*, hopefully more interesting, ways if I can.

I would instead choose a background shape for the text.

Without knowing *what* the text involves... something like...

[image]

Or for dark text...

[image]

Note the box is specifically colored to play off of either the man's coat or the blues in the existing background. It's positioned specifically between her eyes and mouth and ends at her elbow and wrist intentionally. It's *always* favorable to start shapes like this at someone's eye level if there's a face in the image.

[image]

If a larger shape is necessary, I'd consider a cut out for her drink....

[image]

Or a vertical box with a cut out...

[image]

Comment: Much better than the strokes/shadows. Hope OP has seen this answer too.